# keeping track of newly created subviews

Tags: ios, swift

Every time I create a subview I want to update an Int so that I can reference  the specific subview later.

For example,

```
class circularKey: UIView {
    var oscID = 0; //init to zero

    init(origin: CGPoint) {
        oscID = oscID + 1;
        ...
     }
 }
```

Can I have this number update every time I create a new circularKey so that each circularKey has its own unique self.oscID?

Thanks

edit:

I'm now trying to do this from the viewController.swift responsible for adding these subviews.

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var numOscs = 0; //update when we add a new Bosc
    .... 

    ...
    func didTap(tapGR: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

          numOscs = numOscs + 1
          let newCircularKey = circularKeyView(origin: tapPoint, oscIndex: numOscs)

           self.view.addSubview(newCircularKey)
     }
```

my assumption is that upon every didTap numOscs shall be incremented, but it simply stays at zero.  What to do?

Edit2: never mind, it works now :D

I  believe the best solution is to have the invoking controller keep track of how many it has made so far.   Thanks for the help all

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Is the property called `keyID` or `oscID`?

Comment: @matt my bad, i meant for the var to have the same name.  updating code to reflect that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the controller adding the subViews should handle allocating a new ID every time (similarly to tagging buttons)

Regardless, if you did want to create a unique identifier for each subview maybe try creating one with CACurrentMediaTime() as the unique identifier

E.g.

```
class circularKey: UIView {
var keyID = 0.0; //init to zero

init(origin: CGPoint) {
    keyID = CACurrentMediaTime()
    ...
 }
```

}

CACurrentMediaTime() returns the amount of time the app has been active to double precision, so hopefully even adding the sub views in a loop should return unique identifiers each time.

I didn't want to convert the number to an int value and screw up the conversion for you in the main answer but I think you could do:

```
keyID = Int(CACurrentMediaTime()*1000000000) 
//converting to number of nanoseconds since start of the app
```

Double check this though!

As a side note: don't use NSDate for this as it syncs with a server and could 'hiccup' in its value, which could truly be hard to debug later down the line.

Comment: thanks for your kind advice, it works now, I am just using ints and incrementing :)

Answer (score 1):

If your *only* goal is to generate a unique ID every time you create a CircularKey (and you don't care about using sequential numbers to do the job), simply use the NSUUID class to generate the unique ID each time — that's what it's for.